# Printing result of mysql query from variable

Tags: php, mysql

So I wrote this earlier (in php), but everytime I try echo $test", I just get back resource id 5. Does anyone know how to actually print out the mysql query from the variable?

```
$dave= mysql_query("SELECT order_date, no_of_items, shipping_charge, SUM(total_order_amount) as test FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY DATE(`order_date`)") or die(mysql_error());
print $dave;
```

Comment: You need to fetch your result set from `$dave`.  It is merely a MySQL result resource and doesn't hold result rows.

Comment: Read the manual (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for examples.  Besides the official PHP docs, the Internet and SO are positively brimming with examples.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I get easily overwhelmed a lot when trying something new with mysql/php. I appreciate the help though from everyone (and sorry it took me so long to accept an answer)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will print out the query:

```
$query = "SELECT order_date, no_of_items, shipping_charge, SUM(total_order_amount) as test FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY DATE(`order_date`)";

$dave= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
print $query;
```

This will print out the results:

```
$query = "SELECT order_date, no_of_items, shipping_charge, SUM(total_order_amount) as test FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY DATE(`order_date`)";

$dave= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dave)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
    }
    print "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not compatible with PHP7.

Answer (score 5):

well you are returning an array of items from the database. so you need something like this.

```
   $dave= mysql_query("SELECT order_date, no_of_items, shipping_charge, 
    SUM(total_order_amount) as test FROM `orders` 
    WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY DATE(`order_date`)") 
    or  die(mysql_error());


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dave)) {
echo $row['order_date'];
echo $row['no_of_items'];
echo $row['shipping_charge'];
echo $row['test '];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From php docs:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$records = mysql_query($sql);
```

you can change
    LIMIT 1
to
   LIMIT any number you want

This will show you the last INSERTED row first.