# PHP selected mysql data view as number

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting data from mysql database and print it in a webpage. I'm using wamp server. why I can't fetch the data ?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM user WHERE logid = 'root'") or die(mysql_error());
echo $result; //result view as Resource id #7
```

but I count number of rows which equels to root it views as 1

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM user WHERE logid = 'root'") or die(mysql_error());
$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $no_of_rows; //result view as 1
```

Comment: As an aside, the `mysql` extension is deprecated, you should move to PDO. Also, you do not need to quote a variable to echo it. See @ICanHasCheezburger answer.

Comment: There is a ticket already created about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519549/printing-result-of-mysql-query-from-variable

Comment: @Eamonn sorry. I have't use quote there. when I type here I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You use **[mysql_fetch_row()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)** or [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) (to retrieve by column name) as:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
var_dump($row); 
#or echo $row[0]; echo $row[1]; etc. based on the number of columns returned
#if you used mysql_fetch_assoc, you retrieve by echo $row['column1']; etc.
}
```

`$result` is the result set and contains the the total rows returned from the table, use the above function `mysql_fetch_row()` to retrieve each row from it in a loop.

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

Besides of you need to use PDO instead of Mysql, you could try to code your select queries like this:

```
<?php 

$sql = " 
    SELECT 
        userid
    FROM 
        user 
    WHERE
        logid = 'root'
"; 

if(!$res = mysql_query($sql)) 
{ 
    trigger_error(mysql_error().'<br />In query: '.$sql); 
} 
elseif(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) 
{ 
    echo 'No results'; 
} 
else 
{ 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    { 
        echo $row[0].'<br />'; // Use 0 for the first column or the name of the column
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: _[It only returns an associative array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-assoc-description)_. It should be `$row['column_name']`